# Laravel route with & without parameter

Tags: laravel, routes

The question might sound simple but what's the difference between those 2 routes exactly ?
why dont we need to Add parameter for the first route

Routes

```
Route::get('/products', [ProductController::class, 'index'])->name('product.index');

Route::get('/products/{slug}', [ProductController::class, 'show'])->name('product.show');
```

here in blade file

```
<a href="{{route('product.index',['category'=>request()->category,'sort'=>'low_high'])}}">Low to High</a>

<a href="{{route('product.show',$product->slug)}}">High to Low</a>
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code, just copy paste the code into your question.

Comment: Did you read https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-parameters ?

Comment: I didn't understand how we put array of parameter ['category'=>request()->category,'sort'=>'low_high'] without adding parameter to index route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass an array to the `route` helper it will try to match up the keys of that array to the route parameters (if there are any to match up), anything that isn't a route parameter gets added as a query string parameter; so that array isn't just for route parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Your index route shows all elements which is not a specific element.

The show route expects a parameter to show you all details of exactly one item.

Comment: can we pass additional parameters in the array  without passing it to route ?